# tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in python 3

Tags: python, expressões-lambda

Comecei a estudar Python agora e me deparei com esse erro

```
tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in python 3
```

Segue abaixo o trecho do código:

```
#cria uma lista(user_id, numero_de_amigos)

numero_de_amigos_by_id=[(usuario["id"], numero_de_amigos(usuario))for usuario in usuarios]
sorted(numero_de_amigos_by_id, key=lambda (usuario_id, numero_de_amigos):numero_de_amigos, reverse=True)
```

Como faço para resolver isso? o erro está no `key=lambda (usuario_id, numero_de_amigos)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você possui uma lista de tuplas, então na sua expressão lambda, que definiu no parâmetro `key`, você receberá também uma tupla como parâmetro. Ou seja, é passado para a lambda uma tupla com 2 posições e você *espera* dois parâmetros. Dada essa inconsistência o interpretador gera o erro citado, que não é possível desconstruir a tupla passada em dois parâmetros nesse contexto.

Assim, ao invés de esperar dois parâmetros, você deve receber apenas um, que é uma tupla de dois valores, e acessar o valor desejado:

```
sorted(numero_de_amigos_by_id, key=lamba it: it[1], reverse=True)
```

Assim, `it` será uma tupla e você estará acessando a posição 1, referente ao valor de `numero_de_amigos(usuario)`.